# One to one, onto and invertible functions

Tags: functions

So I'm trying to see if this makes sense.

A function $f:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ is said to be invertible if the determinant is different than zero. If it is invertible then it is one-to-one and also onto.

Does this apply for a function $f:\Bbb Z^2 \rightarrow \Bbb Z^2$. Something tells me that this is not a general rule for integers and natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first claim is true only for linear maps, not for functions in general.

A linear functions $f :\Bbb Z^2 \rightarrow \Bbb Z^2$ is invertible if and only if $\det(A_f)=\pm 1$. In general, you need the determinant to be an unit in that ring.

And a function (not necessarily linear) is invertible if and only if it is one-to-one and onto.

Comment: In other words: for the reals, the determinant that is different than zero is said to be invertible which would imply that it is 1-1 and onto. But for integers, it is only invertible iff the determiant is 1 or -1. Correct?

Comment: @Dimitri The bigger issue is that you don't seem to be distinguishing between *linear* functions and *all* functions. For general functions, there is no such thing as "determinant." But yes, it is true that for a commutative ring $R$, a linear $R$- endomorphism of $R^n$ is invertible iff its determinant is a unit in $R$.

Comment: Invertible basically means you can find another number $b$ of the "same type" such that $ab=1$. If $a$ is real, you can find a real $b$ so that $ab=1$ as long as $a \neq 0$. Same happens if $a,b$ are rationals. But if $a,b$ are integers, and $ab=1$ what can $a$ be? And as rschwieb said, be carefull, this only applis to linear mappings.

Comment: Yea, now I'm getting a little confused. Perhaps I should not be using the term function to describe this. The whole idea was to see if there exists a generalized way of determining these three properties specifically for  $f:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$  and  $f:\Bbb Z^2 \rightarrow \Bbb Z^2$